# Get the results with multiple time comparison with a single column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Table **r_job_scores**:

```
Student_id | Skill  | skill-Score
1             PHP         5
1             SQL         1
1             HTML        2
1             CSS         2

2             PHP         10
2             SQL         1

3             PHP         3
3             HTML        -2
3             CSS         2
```

I want to filter the student results:

```
SELECT Student_id
FROM r_job_scores
WHERE SKILL = 'PHP' AND MARKS >= 3 
AND SKILL = 'HTML' AND MARKS >= 2 
AND SKILL = 'CSS' AND MARKS >= 1
AND SKILL = 'SQL' AND MARKS >= 1
```

I want get the list of student in a single query.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your query is that all the conditions can't be satisfied on a single row for a student and hence you get no result.

You can `group by` student_id and use conditional aggregation to check for the specific conditions. This assumes a student_id has at most one row per skill.

```
SELECT Student_id
FROM r_job_scores
GROUP BY Student_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN SKILL = 'PHP' AND MARKS >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN SKILL = 'HTML' AND MARKS >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
AND SUM(CASE WHEN SKILL = 'CSS' AND MARKS >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN SKILL = 'SQL' AND MARKS >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

The query can also be simply expressed in MySQL as

```
SELECT Student_id
FROM r_job_scores
GROUP BY Student_id
HAVING SUM(SKILL = 'PHP' AND MARKS >= 3) = 1
AND SUM(SKILL = 'HTML' AND MARKS >= 2) = 1 
AND SUM(SKILL = 'CSS' AND MARKS >= 1) = 1
AND SUM(SKILL = 'SQL' AND MARKS >= 1) = 1
```

Comment: Not or..! i want a particular students has to pass all that criteria (skills and score).

Comment: @Abdulwaheed I'm pretty sure the word you're looking for is 'thank you'

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY`, use `HAVING` combined with `COUNT DISTINCT` to make sure all 4 different skills are there:

```
SELECT Student_id
FROM r_job_scores
WHERE (SKILL = 'PHP' AND MARKS >= 3)
   OR (SKILL = 'HTML' AND MARKS >= 2)
   OR (SKILL = 'CSS' AND MARKS >= 1)
   OR (SKILL = 'SQL' AND MARKS >= 1)
GROUP BY Student_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SKILL) = 4
```